# How to send user to another activity Push Notifications Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I was reading and I can['t get to an answer, I want to send a push notification to my user, but when the user clicks open a custom intent, I don't want to do this for all the notifications, just for a couple. Let's say I want to send here

[image]

The value to open a custom intent, and then if I don't put anything there, the app will still open the default intent, I need this because I want to send the user sometimes to another activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way to achieve this is to always open the MainActivity and pass the information in your notification data(called as payload schema) to the MainActivity as an intent. In your payload schema you will pass in the information which will help you decide which activity to open. These information will be in form of key value pair. For example you can define a parameter `action` and this will contain an identifier for the activity that you want to open when the notification is clicked.

In your main activity you will have a logic to read this information from your notification schema and redirect it to appropriate activity. Something like this

```
//Main activity code
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   if(action == "Activity1") {
       //start activity 1;
   }
}
```

If you dont pass anything in notification it will by default launch the main activity.